# How to configure Flask Mail properly

Tags: python, flask, flask-mail

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/intro-to-flask-adding-a-contact-page--net-28982).  When I try to submit the contact form, which should trigger the email, I get an internal server error. The error log says:

```
RuntimeError: The curent application was not configured with Flask-Mail
```

The instructions say to use `from flask.ext.mail` to import but I've seen that it might be `from flask_mail` now. I've also tried changing the mail port from 465 to 587. Neither of these changes have been fixed the problem. My most up to date code is:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash
from forms import ContactForm
from flask_mail import Mail, Message

mail = Mail()

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = 'development key'

app.config["MAIL_SERVER"] = "smtp.gmail.com"
app.config["MAIL_PORT"] = 587
app.config["MAIL_USE_SSL"] = True
app.config["MAIL_USERNAME"] = 'contact_email@gmail.com'  ## CHANGE THIS
app.config["MAIL_PASSWORD"] = 'password'

mail.init_app(app)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'Oh Wow This Is A Super Secret Development Key'


@app.route('/')
def home():
  return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/about')
def about():
  return render_template('about.html')

@app.route('/contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
  form = ContactForm()

  if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.validate() == False:
      flash('All fields are required.')
      return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
    else:
      msg = Message(form.subject.data, sender='contact_email@gmail.com', recipients=['recipient@gmail.com'])
      msg.body = """
      From: %s &lt;%s&gt;
      %s
      """ % (form.name.data, form.email.data, form.message.data)
      mail.send(msg)

      return render_template('contact.html', success=True)

  elif request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('contact.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a second app (presumably by accident) after configuring the initial app.  Right now the "first" `app` is configured and has the extension registered, but the "second" `app` is used to register the routes and call `.run()`.

Remove the line after `mail.init_app(app)`, the second `app = Flask(__name__)` that creates another app.